# Can I compose two JSON Schemas in a third one?

Tags: jsonschema, openapi

I want to describe the JSON my API will return using JSON Schema, referencing the schemas in my OpenAPI configuration file.

I will need to have a different schema for each API method. Let’s say I support `GET /people` and `GET /people/{id}`. I know how to define the schema of a "person" once and reference it in both `/people` and `/people/{id}` using `$ref`.

[EDIT: See a (hopefully) clearer example at the end of the post]

What I don’t get is how to define and reuse the structure of my response, that is:

```
{
   "success": true,
   "result" : [results]
}

or

{
   "success": false,
   "message": [string]
}
```

Using `anyOf` (both for the success/error format check, and for the results, referencing various schemas (`people-multi.json`, `people-single.json`), I can define a "root schema" `api-response.json`, and I can check the general validity of the JSON response, but it doesn’t allow me to check that the `/people` call returns an array of people and not a single person, for instance.

How can I define an `api-method-people.json` that would include the general structure of the response (from an external schema of course, to keep it DRY) and inject another schema in `result`?

### EDIT: A more concrete example (hopefully presented in a clearer way)

I have two JSON schemas describing the response format of my two API methods: `method-1.json` and `method-2.json`.

I could define them like this (not a schema here, I’m too lazy):

`method-1.json` :

```
{
  success: (boolean),
  result: { id: (integer), name: (string) }
}
```

`method-2.json` :

```
{
  success: (boolean),
  result: [ (integer), (integer), ... ]
}
```

But I don’t want to repeat the structure (first level of the JSON), so I want to extract it in a `response-base.json` that would be somehow (?) referenced in both `method-1.json` and `method-2.json`, instead of defining the success and result properties for every method.

In short, I guess I want some kind of composition or inheritance, as opposed to inclusion (permitted by `$ref`).

Comment: You would again use $ref references, but HOW that exactly works within the tooling you're using may vary.

Comment: A note, prior to OpenAPI 3.1 (currently in RC), you can't use pure JSON Schema, but rather a subset supset of JSON Schema defined by OAI. From 3.1, you can use FULL JSON Schema, which will hopefully make this a lot easier... but of course, you're looking for a solution today, not in 3 months time.

Comment: How would that be related to the tooling I’m using? The way I see it, either the JSON Schema specification defines a way to do that, either it doesn’t… right?

Comment: While JSON Schema does indeed support this, prior to OpenAPI 3.1, JSON Schema quite what's used. Some OpenAPI tooling may support referencing external files, some might not, and AFAIK, doing so isn't defined in the OpenAPI spec itself. You'll have to look at tooling docs.

Comment: Ok good to know! Can you give me some pointers as to how JSON Schema supports this? Even if the tools I use don’t support it. I just don’t know how to define an `api-call-people.json` schema saying basically "`api-call-base.json` with `people.json` in the `result` field." I can’t find that in the documentation.

Comment: Based on your question, you were almost there, and actually you might just need to use the `items` keyword for the situation where you expect an array of things as opposed to just one thing. I don't have enough information in your question to give you a specific answer from your question. Could you provide a FULL example of what you've tried so far please?

Comment: @Relequestual I just edited my question with another example, I hope it will be clearer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221881/discussion-between-relequestual-and-niavlys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So JSON Schema doesn’t allow this kind of composition, at least in a simple way or before draft 2019-09 (thanks @Relequestual!).

However, I managed to make it work in my case. I first separated the two main cases ("result" vs. "error") in two base schemas `api-result.json` and `api-error.json`. (If I want to return an error, I just point to the `api-error.json` schema.)

In the case of a proper API result, I define a schema for a given operation using `allOf` and `$ref` to extend the base result schema, and then redefine the `result` property:

```
{
  "$schema: "…",
  "$id": "…/api-result-get-people.json",
  "allOf": [{ "$ref": "api-result.json" }],
  "properties": {
    "result": {
       …
    }
  }
}
```

*(Edit: I was previously using just `$ref` at the top level, but it doesn’t seem to work)*

This way I can point to this `api-result-get-people.json`, and check the general structure (`success` key with a value of `true`, and a required `result` key) as well as the specific form of the result for this "get people" API method.